# Вопрос о происхождении слова "личность"

Tags: этимология, морфология

Связаны ли между собой слова: "личность", "лик", "ликовать"? Если, да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

Лик-(поэт.уст.)-лицо, переносное знач."внешние очертания, облик".

Ликовать - заимствовано из ст.-слав. языка в др.-русск.период. В старославянском образовано от сущ. ЛИКЪ-"пение, танцы, пляски" -заимствованного из гот.яз., где laiks-"танец, пляски".

Личность -  по мнению В. В. Виноградова, не ранее второй половины XVII в.слово было образовано от имени прилагательного личный как отвлечённое существительное на -ость и обозначало: «принадлежащий, свойственный какому-нибудь лицу»

Все исследователи сходятся во мнении, что существительное личность восходит к церковнославянскому ликъ в значении лицо, образ (которому в древнерусском языке соответствовало слово лице).

Вместе с тем слово личность не могло появиться ранее XVII в. - отсутствовал его денотат. В. В. Виноградов пишет: «В древнерусском языке до XVII в. не было потребности в слове, которое соответствовало бы, хотя отдаленно, современным представлениям и понятиям о личности, индивидуальности, особи» В древнерусских текстах представление о личности как выделяющейся из массы особи передавалось с помощью разных слов (челов^къ, душа, лице, существо и пр.) но ни одно из них не имело этического оттенка смысла» .
 Слово лицо до начала XVIII в. не обозначало человека вообще, индивидуума, персонаж, так же как и не выражало до XIX в. значения: `индивидуальный облик, отличительные черты, совокупность индивидуальных признаков' (иметь, приобрести свое лицо)

В. В. Колесов замечает, что «особа-точная калька с латинского сочетания per se, известная и в такой передаче - персона. Это точное соответствие слову лице, а значение, которым наделяется личность, связано с признаком самостоятельности, самодостаточности существования». Об этом упоминает и Н. Н. Вольский: «уже в классическую эпоху persona означает также “лицо, особа, человек, личность”. Но параллельно с прямым заимствованием слово персона породило в русском языке и слово личность, поскольку его, в определённом смысле, можно считать калькой латинского слова»

Answer (score 1):

Диакон Андрей Кураев заявил в своем видео, что слово "личность" ввел в оборот Карамзин. Я погуглил, подтверждения этому не нашел. Только косвенные... Думаю, слова личность, лик, ликовать - однокоренные. Связь такая: ликовать - светиться лицом, выражать радость на лице. Лик же - это не простое лицо, это что то возвышенное. Лик бога. Личность - это не безликий индивид, а человек со своими отличительными особенностями, которого не спутаешь с безликим. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Илья, Ваше мнение очень интересное, но дело вот в чем, касаясь арабского языка. В арабском языке нет слова "личность", т. е. нет ему такого точного соответствия, как в церковнославянском, вот лишь по этой причине в исламе Бог и не является личностью, потому что слово "личность" в арабском означает "парнишка", а не то, как транслируете вы. И из-за вроде незначительного слова происходит подмена религиозных понятий, которые в корне извращают истинные свойства Бога, и вводят в заблуждение целые поколения народов, желающих быть с истинным Богом. А личность это Тот, кто имеет лик, т. е. образ. Образ - это то, чему нужно следовать, т. е. "образец", эталон.

А как мы видим до XVIII в. слово "лик" не означает человеческую индивидуальность, особенность, а является образом Божьим, которому нужно следовать, уподоблять свою личность богоподобию, отрекаясь от греховного деланья. "Личность" неверно понимает современное общество, хотя люди и являются личностями, т. к. созданы по образу и подобию Божьему, личность подразумевает свободу выбора: у Бога свободная воля и над ним нет властвующих, так и человек наделен свободным выбором. Человеку предложено: быть с Источником Жизни, наследуя Царствие Небесное, или погибнуть для вечности, но на земле искать лишь спокойствия и безмятежности, искать пышности, удобств. "Личность", чаще ошибочно,  воспринимается современными людьми как самость, человеческая автономность, вне Бога, т. е. одаривание себя самого медалью исключительности, и не дай Бог похожести на кого-либо, это самомнение, самонадеянность, самодостаточность, обостренного "я" в себе самом. Приписываем победы своей исключительности, своим стараниям, своей мнимой праведности. Так как в наше сердце с грехом вошла гордость, которая есть самолюбие, эгоизм. Но самодостаточность характерна не для человека, а для Того, кто является полнотой жизни и источником жизни. Человек не самосущен, в нем нет собственного источника жизни, так как человек личность сотворенная, а личностью человек зовется, т. к. мы образ и подобие Божие.
Поэтому "личность" в арабском языке по сути не существует, а является адаптацией переводчиков на русский язык, но не отражает истинного значения, которые скрывается в древнерусском языке. Человек должен в Бога богатеть, а арабская интерпретация лишена Бога Любви и подспудно учит накоплению богатства земного, богатства иллюзорного, а не покаянию и не духовной брани своей души, а учит ликвидации "неправоверных". Вот какая "несущественная" на первый взгляд разница.